# How do I trigger a callback when a NSAnimationContext ends?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-animation

I have an animation which moves some views around. When this animation completes I want the window to recalculate the keyview loop. My code is simmilar to the follow mock code:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];        
[newView setAlpha: 0.0]; //hide newView
[self addSubView:newView];

//position the views
[[oldView animator] setFrame: newFrame1];
[[newView animator] setFrame: newFrame2];

[[newView animator] setAlpha: 1.0]; //fade-in newView

[NSAnimationContext endGrouping]; 

[[self window] recalculateKeyViewLoop];
```

The problem with this code is that `recalculateKeyViewLoop` is called before the views are in their new positions which means that the keyviewloop is wrong.

How do I fix this?

My first though is to call `recalculateKeyViewLoop` in a callback from when the animation ends but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Something that's not so obvious, or at least wasn't to me, is that there are two animations going on when you do a `setFrame:`, with keys `frameSize` and `frameOrigin`.

Depending on what your original and final frames are you may need to register yourself as a delegate for one or both of them.

I'd also recommend that you make a copy of the animation you get back from `-animationForKey:` and store your modified copy in the `animations` dictionary of your object. This way your delegate will only be called at the conclusion of that particular objects' animator duration, versus all objects animating that key.

eg.

```
CAAnimation *animation = [[view animationForKey:@"frameOrigin"] copy];
animation.delegate = self;
[view setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:animation forKey:@"frameOrigin"]];
```

In this way your animation object will supersede the default animation object for that view. Then implement whichever delegate methods you're interested in.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to send `-animationForKey:` to your views to get a `CAAnimation` instance, then set yourself as its delegate and implement the method that [Adam mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330609/how-do-i-trigger-a-callback-when-a-nsanimationcontext-ends#330759).

Answer (score 1):

if you use CAAnimation this has an animationDidStop:finished: delegate method..

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAAnimation

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use a completion handler like this:

```
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context){
    // Start some animations.
    [[myView animator] setFrameSize:newViewSize];
    [[myWindow animator] setFrame:newWindowFrame display:YES];
} completionHandler:^{
    // This block will be invoked when all of the animations started above have completed or been cancelled.
    NSLog(@"All done!");
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my post here: [How would I do this iOS animation on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788998/how-would-i-do-this-ios-animation-on-osx/7880009#7880009)

I wrote a class that handles this for you, using blocks. Hopefully your target allows blocks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are animating an `NSWindow` (as opposed to an `NSView`), the other answers will not work and you should do this instead:

```
CAAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.delegate = self;
self.window.animations = @{@"frame": animation};
[[self.window animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 200) display:YES];
```

which will then call the `animationDidStop:finished:` method on your delegate (which in the above code would be `self`)