# How would I do this iOS animation on OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa, uiview, core-animation

I have a very simple animation in iOS that fades a view, resizes a container to fit another view, then fades that other view back in. It's quite easy to do and very straightforward.

I've been trying to do something pretty much exactly like this on OSX, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it. The animation stuff on OSX feels so clunky and difficult compared to iOS.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Thanks! :)

```
// Fade out viewOne, resize frame to fit viewTwo, fade in viewTwo
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.15
        animations: ^{
            [viewOne setAlpha:0.0];
        }
        completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2
                    animations: ^{
                        [self setFrame: [viewTwo frame]];
                    }
                    completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                        [viewTwo setAlpha: 0.0];
                        [self addSubview: viewTwo];
                        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.15
                                animations: ^{
                                    [viewTwo setAlpha:1.0];
                                }];
                    }];
         }];
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've written a small class that uses blocks to accomplish essentially the same thing as above when using the animator proxy on OSX.

Please note, this class is not thread safe and hasn't undergone any specific or stressful tests.

```
//Interface
@interface MZAnimator : NSObject{}

+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                  animation:(void (^)(void))animationBlock;
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                  animation:(void (^)(void))animationBlock
                 completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock;
@end


//Implementation
@interface MZAnimator ()
+ (void)runEndBlock:(void (^)(void))completionBlock;
@end

@implementation MZAnimator

+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                  animation:(void (^)(void))animationBlock
{
  [self animateWithDuration:duration animation:animationBlock completion:nil];
}
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                  animation:(void (^)(void))animationBlock
                 completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{
  [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
  [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:duration];
  animationBlock();
  [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

  if(completionBlock)
  {
    id completionBlockCopy = [[completionBlock copy] autorelease];
    [self performSelector:@selector(runEndBlock:) withObject:completionBlockCopy afterDelay:duration];
  }
}

+ (void)runEndBlock:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{
  completionBlock();
}
@end
```

Comment: Nice solution :-) To make it even more like `UIView` this could be implemented as a category of `NSView`; the animations would then be invoked as class methods of `NSView`.

Comment: A great idea! A few class functions could streamline and refine the usage. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it works. But which libraries do I need to make it workable?

Comment: Using the completion handler of the current `NSAnimationContext` would be much besser than dispatching a timer, which can be really inaccurate.

Answer (score 19):

You can use:

```
  [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    [context setDuration:2.0];
    //Animation code
  } completionHandler:^{
    //Completion Code
    NSLog(@"Completed");
  }];
```

Comment: I have tried this and its rubbish. Its so slow and laggy and when using with objects like NSButtons, the background color disappears when the animation starts.