# Animate Transition in objective c

Tags: cocoa, animation, nsview, nsanimation

How to give animation to NSView? The function which is used for animation in ios is as below.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: duration
                                      delay:0.0
                                    options:curve
                                 animations:updateClocks
                                 completion:nil];
```

I want to use the same function in mac os for animation. So how can I use this function with given parameters for mac os x?

Answer (score 0):

That is because animateWithDuration is only available for iOS and tVOS. You can see it in Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration

[image]

You need to find the equivalent one in MacOSX.

Comment: @ronakpatel check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20353452/501439